# Scikit Learn _ufuncs error in Jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, data-science

Scikit learn has had _ufuncs errors for the past week and I can't figure out why. I'm using python on anaconda and a Dell computer, while using Jupyter notebooks. It was previously fine until last week when I got these issues

[image: ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _ufuncs: The specified procedure could not be found.]

I've looked on other stack overflow questions and tried them. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling scipy using pip and conda. Uninstalling and reinstalling anaconda navigator doesn't work. Uninstalling and reinstalling icc_rt didn't work at all either. I got scikit learn to work after uninstalling and reinstalling mkl, but after that it stopped working. Any help would be much appreciated because the only idea I can come up with is to factory reset my computer and see if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reporting that this fails:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean
```

After executing `$ conda install -c conda-forge scipy`
I obtain "scipy 1.9.3 py310h240c617_2 conda-forge"
for the 3.10.6 interpreter.
Having installed it,
the `import` happens without a hitch.

Consider installing the package into a fresh [conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) environment.